# Return the JSONObject response in method

Tags: android, json, jsonresult

I want to return the result or response of JSONObject But response is not able to return. HOw to do this?

```
private String requestJSON(String stringURI) {

     JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, stringURI, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     //Here I want to return this  response  at the end of this method
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);


     return response.toString;
    }
```

Comment: show your work please

Comment: I just want to convert the response into a string and return... Nothing else and all the code related to that is above

Comment: You are trying to mess sync flow with async flow. The only place to handle response is onResponse method. You can declare such method anywhere inside your app and pass it here as reference.

Comment: ahhh Thanks man, i fogot that volley is async..again thanks